# How to configure postfix to resend soft bounces after X hours on Debian

Tags: postfix

This is a complete noob question for postfix, but I have to administer a live installation, and in need of reconfiguring the resend rate.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `delay_warning_time` parameter, set it to say, 4h to behave a bit like sendmail :

```
delay_warning_time (default: 0h)
       The  time  after  which the sender receives the message headers of mail
       that is still queued.

       To enable this feature, specify a  non-zero  time  value  (an  integral
       value plus an optional one-letter suffix that specifies the time unit).

       Time units: s (seconds), m (minutes), h (hours), d (days),  w  (weeks).
       The default time unit is h (hours).
```

That is, either do a :

```
postconf -e delay_warning_time=4h
```

or edit the main.cf file and put `delay_warning_time=4h`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what partoa is looking for -- It sounds like he wants to configure the actual resend (retry) rate, not how long it takes postfix to send the originator a "Hey I'm still trying to deliver that message" email.  (I could be misreading the original Q. though)

Comment: @voretaq7. True
@mat. Thanks, I bet I'll need this sometime too. Can you, you can add the bit for the retry rate too.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters `minimal_backoff_time`, `maximum_backoff_time` and `queue_run_delay` might help you.

> maximal_backoff_time (default: 4000s)
>
> ```
> The maximal time between attempts to deliver a deferred message.
>
> This parameter should be set to a value greater than or equal to
> ```
>
> $minimal_backoff_time. See also
>   $queue_run_delay.
>
> ```
> Time units: s (seconds), m (minutes), h (hours), d (days), w
> ```
>
> (weeks). The default time unit is s
>   (seconds).

For more information see [the Postfix documentation about the parameters](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)